# Drawing boxes using Ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses

I am currently trying to draw a set of boxes using ncurses. At this moment I have variables that represent the length and width of these boxes. One thing is that I am not allowed to use commands like
 "`WINDOW * win = newwin(10, 10, 1, 1);`".

If I can provide any other information to help you help me, let me know.

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you want to do?

Answer (score 8):

For the boxes, you could use this function:

```
void rectangle(int y1, int x1, int y2, int x2)
{
    mvhline(y1, x1, 0, x2-x1);
    mvhline(y2, x1, 0, x2-x1);
    mvvline(y1, x1, 0, y2-y1);
    mvvline(y1, x2, 0, y2-y1);
    mvaddch(y1, x1, ACS_ULCORNER);
    mvaddch(y2, x1, ACS_LLCORNER);
    mvaddch(y1, x2, ACS_URCORNER);
    mvaddch(y2, x2, ACS_LRCORNER);
}
```

Comment: Also to _just_ draw a box, you can use the function of the same name: [`int box(WINDOW *win, chtype verch, chtype horch);`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_border.3x.html).