# Problem with printing extended ascii using ncurses

Tags: c, linux, debian, ascii, ncurses

I have got problem with printing extended ascii in terminal using wprintw function. This program prints letters instead squares. I was trying to change my locales but without effect. What should I change in my system to print it correctly?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    initscr();
    WINDOW *game_window;
    game_window=newwin(40,40,1,1);
    wrefresh(game_window);

    while (TRUE) {
        wclear(game_window);
        wprintw(game_window, "██████████████████████");
        wrefresh(game_window);
        sleep(3);
        break;
    }
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

I am working On Debian Jessie 10 and these are my locale:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: In addition to what Dan points out, are you aware of those functions: [Drawing boxes using Ncurses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22399406/1606345)? You also may be interested in: https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_border.3x.html

Comment: I can't 'draw' box I must print it using wprintw. In function wprintw you can't add letter L before your string. Changing LC_ALL to LC_CTYPE also didn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I find the solution, when compiling the program you should use
this command:

```
gcc main.c -o main -lncursesw
```

Instead this:

```
gcc main.c -o main -lncurses
```